How to get hash of newly rebased commit in Mercurial
I'm trying to write an alias for mercurial that will reabse a commit with HashA, and then hg up to the newly rebased commit.
My problem is I don't know how to programatically get the new commit hash. Is this possible?
My current alias:
function rs() {
  stable
  hg rebase -s "$1" -d stable
  hg co "$1 // <--- this just goes to the old commit, not the rebased commit 
  hg ssl
}

